# ASP.NET MVC 2 Pure jquery client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I go about hooking up my validation with jquery only? I do not want to use Microsoft ajax. I saw on [this blog](http://www.henrycordes.nl/post/2010/04/ASPNET-MVC-20-with-jQuery-validation.aspx) exactly what I want, but it seems that the file `MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidator.js` is deprecated or canceled.

Is there an official way to do this now? Possibly using asp.net mvc 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to achieve this is already included with the ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Beta 1 template.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") %>"></script>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Value) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

If you want to do the same thing with ASP.NET MVC 2.0 you will need to download the source code of [ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110348) and extract `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` from the package to include in your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/